# Which URL to use for Google Maps for China?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, great-firewall-of-china

I want to load the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), and I want it to be accessible from within the [Great Firewall of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall).

Google [recommends](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#https-or-http) `http://maps.google.cn`, but if I use this it might be slower for people in other parts of the world.

From what I've read, The Great Firewall of China doesn't block `http://` addresses from Google, so I might be able to use `http://maps.googleapis.com/` also.

Has anyone tried this out and can you offer advice on which one is better to use, in terms of *reliability* and *speed*?

N.B. I don't want to use Baidu Maps.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're restricted with using Maps in China, you'll really be restricted in HTTP. This is their answer from the [FAQs page](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#china_ws_access)

> **Why can't I access Google Maps APIs from China?**
>
> The Google Maps APIs are served within China from the domain maps.google.cn. This domain does not support https. When making requests to the Google Maps APIs from China, please replace https://maps.googleapis.com with http://maps.google.cn.
>
> For example:
>
> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA`
>   would become:
>
> `http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA`
>
> The Google Maps JavaScript API can be loaded with the following bootstrap:
>
> `<script src="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"
>       type="text/javascript">
>   </script>`

I cannot comment in terms of reliability and speed, but I guess it will still be the same since Google still handles it. @scaisedge's answer can give you his experience with the domain change.

Comment: What about google places using the same the result is 404 error

Comment: I confirm that this method does not work for google places.

Answer (score 0):

I  tried an application that makes heavy use goggle maps v3 both :  using the API standard and  using those provided by China.
I did not notice problems appreciable slowdown indeed in some cases, access to the site of China with the use of the API has detected more performative than the normal use of the API. If there are situations of slowdown think they are related to the normal load flow characteristic of the Internet.