# Using Google Places API in China

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I need adapt Android app for using in China, and there are Google Maps with objects by Google Places

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34521479/1448011 I found that http://maps.google.cn is identical for https://maps.googleapis.com. Unfortunately it's available only geocode function of api.

How to use other functions of Google Places like https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=... ?

Because http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/place/details/json responds 404 error

Comment: Also try commenting on that answer, for the one that answered may be able to see it. He may also be familiar with what you need. ;)

Comment: I think what are you doing is correct, because if you consider the [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#google-maps-api-services), that is the way to use it to access China. Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802180/how-to-access-google-maps-api-in-china) if it can help you. Also try to follow what McAwesomville recommended to you.

Comment: Any updates on this ?